# Value of the variable passed as reference gets changed in threads

Tags: c, pthreads, pthread-join

I wrote this small program for understanding pthread_create and pthread_join but I dont understand why the value of the variable `data` gets altered after thread_join. Its printed as 0 after the call to pthread functions.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void* compute_prime (void* arg)
{
        int n = *((int*) arg);
        printf("Argument passed is %d\n",n);
        return (void *)n;
}
int main ()
{
        pthread_t thread;
        int data = 5000;
        int value=0;

        pthread_create (&thread, NULL, &compute_prime, &data);
        pthread_join (thread, (void*) &value);
        printf("The number is %d and return value is %d.\n", data, value);
        return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
Argument passed is 5000
The number is 0 and return value is 5000.
```

Comment: `value` in `pthread_join` is set to the return value of the thread. Herein, this means that would be the value of `n` returned by the thread function

Comment: @CraigEstey the question is why `data` changes. And I don't see anything in this code changing it, even with the ill cast in `return (void *)n;`. There might be code missing.

Comment: `return (void *)n;` is returning a pointer to a local variable, isn't it?

Comment: @duong_dajgja no, it just casts the `int` to a `void *`. But this isn't a safe thing to do in general. (and it's indeed the source of the problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `pthread_join` has the prototype `void **`. It expects a *pointer* to an object of type `void *`; it modifies this `void *` object. Now it so happens that you're running on a 64-bit arch, where `data` and `value` are both 32 bits, and laid out in memory sequentially. Modifying a `void *` object that is laid out in memory starting from the address of the `int` object `value` clobbers the `int` object `data` too, as these are both 32 bits - thus you will see that the `data` was overwritten. However, this is undefined behaviour so anything might happen.

---

Don't use casts as they will only serve to hide problems. Casting to a `void *` is especially dangerous as a `void *` can be converted to any other type implicitly, even to `void **`, even though usually it too would be incorrect. If you remove the cast, you most probably will get a warning or an error like

```
thrtest.c: In function ‘main’:
thrtest.c:16:31: error: passing argument 2 of ‘pthread_join’ from 
                incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
         pthread_join (thread, &value);
```

if compiling with warnings enabled.

---

If however you really want to do this, you must do it like this:

```
void *value;
pthread_join(thread, &value);
intptr_t value_as_int = (intptr_t)value;
```

Though it is not really portable either, as the conversion is implementation-defined.

The most portable way to return an integer is to return a pointer to a `malloc`ated object:

```
int *return_value = malloc(sizeof (int));
*return_value = 42;
return return_value;

...

void *value;
pthread_join(thread, &value);
int actual = *(int *)value;
free(value);
```

Comment: if you just want to return a number from a thread function, converting it to `intptr_t` comes to mind, though...

Comment: yeah, then can confirm this by defining data as `unsigned long long int`?

Comment: @duong_dajgja no.

Comment: The only portability issue with `intptr_t` would be the range of values representable in `void *`.... As this is a POSIX function, it would be an interesting question whether POSIX is giving guarantees that make this bullet-proof (it's somewhat common to return a single number that way, at least)

Comment: You certainly can take an arbitrary pointer, convert it to `intptr_t` on POSIX and then back again, but I would be a bit more hesitant about converting an arbitrary integer to a pointer...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes, it must be representable in `void *` and that's not guaranteed by C. But maybe it is by POSIX, I don't know...